# Getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in python dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary in python :

```
aDict = {
    'form-1-device': ['2'],
    'form-0-test_group': ['1'],
    'form-1-test_scenario': ['3'],
}
```

i need to remove the `form-1-device` with `device` and so on from dict . So far i have tried this:

```
for k,v in bDict.iteritems():
    newk = [k[k.find('-',5)+1:]] 
    print newk
    aDict[newk] = aDict[k]
    del aDict[k]
```

or instead of

```
 aDict[newk] = aDict[k]
 del aDict[k]
```

This will also do the job

```
aDict[newk] = aDict.pop(k)
```

My expected output is :

```
aDict = {
    'device': ['2'],
    'test_group': ['1'],
    'test_scenario': ['3'],
}
```

But it gives an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' in python dict`
SO far i looked in to [Python dictionary : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532146/python-dictionary-typeerror-unhashable-type-list) and [Python, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371358/python-typeerror-unhashable-type-list)
also had a look to this [Python creating dictionary key from a list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277417/python-creating-dictionary-key-from-a-list-of-items)
But nothing worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its because of that dictionary keys are hashable objects and you are trying to assign an unhashable object (list) to your key. so instead of `newk = [k[k.find('-',5)+1:]]` do `newk = k[k.find('-',5)+1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
newk = [k[k.find('-',5)+1:]]
```

`newk` is a list, not a string. Remove square brackets and your code should work.

There is a good explanation why lists can't be used as dictionary keys - https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

Also I would recommend you to use dictionary comprehensions to create a new dictionary and bind `aDict` name to it.

```
aDict = {
    'form-1-device': ['2'],
    'form-0-test_group': ['1'],
    'form-1-test_scenario': ['3'],
    }

aDict = {k[k.find('-',5)+1:]:v for k, v in aDict.iteritems()}
```

Comment: really appreciated. Nice and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

You crate the new key here:

```
newk = [k[k.find('-',5)+1:]]
```

Which produces `['device']`. That's a list (which can't be used as a dictionary key, since it is not hashable)… You need to get rid of the outer brackets:

```
newk = k[k.find('-',5)+1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply messed up creating a new key - dicts are implemented as hash-maps and requires hashable objects as their keys. You are clearly passing single-element list (square brackets around `newk` variable).

Is this works OK?

```
d = {
    'form-1-device': ['2'],
    'form-0-test_group': ['1'],
    'form-1-test_scenario': ['3'],
    }

for k,v in d.iteritems():
    new_key = k.split('-')[2]
    d[new_key] = d.pop(k)

expected = {
    'device': ['2'],
    'test_group': ['1'],
    'test_scenario': ['3'],
    }

assert d == expected
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer . self explanatory  +1 .:)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets from the `newk` assignment and use `items` instead of `iteritems`

```
for k,v in bDict.items():
    newk = k[k.find('-',5)+1:]
    print newk
    aDict[newk] = aDict[k]
    del aDict[k]
```